# Pip freeze > requirements doesn't work well with anaconda

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to create a virtual environment based on another, for this, I want to extract the information from the libraries for a Django environment with pip freeze> requirements.txt

But the output is

```
asgiref @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
cryptography==3.4.7
cycler==0.10.0
Django @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/django_1613762073373/work
django-clear-cache==0.3
djangorestframework==3.12.4
idna==2.10
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.4.1
numpy==1.20.2
Pillow==8.2.0
psycopg2 @ file:///C:/ci/psycopg2_1612298766762/work
pycparser==2.20
PyMySQL==1.0.2
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyQt5==5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.8.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pytz_1612215392582/work
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sqlparse_1602184451250/work
urllib3==1.26.4
wincertstore==0.2
```

When I try pip install -r requirements.txt doesn't work.

Output

```
Processing c:\tmp\build\80754af9\asgiref_1605055780383\work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\tmp\\build\\80754af9\\asgiref_1605055780383\\work'
```

So I need a way to extract info with pip and install it with pip in another environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you'd like to extract your requirements using `pip`, without any additional info (like the ones you posted), use:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Anyone knows how I can put an emoji in comments? I would like to leave here a heart. THANKS, A LOT

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
conda list --export > requirements.txt
```

to get all the dependencies.

and when creating a new conda environment with the requirement dependencies use

```
conda create --name <envname> --file requirements.txt
```

to know more about the difference btw `conda` and `pip` refer [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/)

you might also find [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html#conda-vs-pip-vs-virtualenv-commands) table helpful, it compares the different commands of `pip` and `conda`